# jquery syntax - why the need for an array index with a textbox?

Tags: jquery, syntax

Can someone tell me why an array index is used in line 5 the following code? '#agree' refers to a checkbox and '#terms' refers to a textbox. The purpose is to determine if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the textbox before the checkbox can be clicked. Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#agree').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

  $('#terms').scroll(function() {
    var textarea_height = $(this)[0].scrollHeight;
    var scroll_height = textarea_height - $(this).innerHeight();

    var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (scroll_top == scroll_height){
      $('#agree').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: zerkms answered, however you can get the value via var h = $(this).prop('scrollHeight')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `scrollHeight` is a DOM-element property.

So `$(this)` is a jQuery object, and `$(this)[0]` is a DOM-element underneath it (you can also use `.get(0)` instead of `[0]`)

`this.scrollHeight` - this should be the same as `$(this)[0].scrollHeight`